# Why is my AJAX request failing?

Tags: ruby, ajax, coffeescript

I'm trying to learn to use AJAX with Rails.

Here is my client side coffeescript code:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#url").blur ->
    $.get("/test_url?url=" + $(this).val(), (data) ->
      alert("Response code: " + data)
    ).fail( () ->
      alert("Why am I failing?")
    )
```

Here is my server-side Ruby code:

```
  def url_response
    url = URI.parse(params[:url])
    Net::HTTP.get_response(url).code unless url.port.nil?
  end
```

The Ruby code is being called and correctly returns the HTTP response code, but I can't do anything with the data because the client-side script says the call has failed. As far as I can see, it is not failing. `url_response` is being called and it is returning a value, so what exactly is failing here?

Comment: What does your rails app's development.log say? Can you open the same URL directly in the browser (without Ajax)?

Comment: I previously was able to open the URL in my browser and get the results, but I forgot I changed the code after that, when I went back and checked I noticed I couldn't open the URL either. I fixed the url_response method to render the result and it worked! Thanks for the hint Fredrick, it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I removed the line that rendered the response. I previously had in, but thanks to Frederick Cheung's hint to check if the URL works directly in the browser, I realised that it no longer worked in the browser as it did previously, which is why I didn't think to check again!

The code below got everything working again.

```
  def url_response
    url = URI.parse(params[:url])
    render :text => Net::HTTP.get_response(url).code unless url.port.nil?
  end
```